# Java multi client server application - how to organise sockets

Tags: java, sockets, vector, client

_Hey, I have a question. I want to write application which will have multiple chats, rooms etc.
And now i have some troubles with server. My conception is to store data of clients in Vector of ClientSocket classes.

ClientSocket class will be like this:

```
public class ClientSocket {
    int client_id;
    Socket socket;
}
```

On main server thread:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
Vector<ClientSocket> sockets;
```

And the idea is: when new connection is established, make a new thread, pass sockets vector as a parameter, generate player id, iterate through vector elements, check if client_id exists, if not, set the id, if yes, generate next and do the same.

And where is the problem? Im worried about synchronization. What will happen, if two clients arrive at same time, and vector size will change in the meantime? Am i doing it correct? Maby there is a better idea to organise it?

Thanks in advance
Marcin

// edit

I meant that situation, but i think i will use Peter Lawrey solution :

[image: Situation]

Comment: `Vector` is synchronized, and you can always synchronize yourself anyway. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to look up the client by client_id I would use a Map. If you use a ConcurrentMap it will be thread safe.

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Socket> socketByClientIdMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// check if a client exists already,
if (socketByClientIdMap.containsKey(clientId))

//  add a socket by client id.
socketByClientIdMap.put(clientId, socket);

// get a socket for a client_id
Socket s = socketByClientIdMap.get(clientId);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen, if two clients arrive at same time, and vector size
>   will change in the meantime?

Since on a new connection you create a new thread (as you say in your post)

> when new connection is established, make a new thread, pass sockets
>   vector as a parameter

then you have 2 threads for the 2 clients that arrive at the same time.
As a result 2 threads operate on the `Vector` that you use.

`Vector` as a class is itself `synchronized` so there is no harm done.

But also `Vector` is considered a rather deprecated collection so perhaps you would want to use newer collection data structures like `List` which are unsynchronized though and will have to either use a syncronized [wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) offered from `Collection`s or synchronize yourself.